# How to keep variables in dynamic array for a limited time

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, timer, stopwatch

I have a c# winforms application which downloads content from certain webpages and puts it in a string variable called `content`. It then searches for specific keywords (contained in a string, and separated by comma) within `content`, and sounds an alarm if there's a match; otherwise, makes another webrequest and run the search again.

My client asked for something different: He wants the program to keep running after it finds a keyword and triggers the alarm, but this time it should only look for the remaining keywords that were not found in the last 5 minutes.

I thought about adding found keywords to a dynamic array, called `foundKeywordsList`, and starting a stopwatch or some kind of timer to remove them from the array after 5 minutes' passed, but I don't know how to do just that, so that's my question. So far this is the relevant code (it runs inside a loop):

```
List<string> foundKeywordsList = new List<string>();

string keywords = "scott,mark,tom,bob,sam";

string[] keywordArray = keywords.Split(',');

foreach (string kw in keywordArray)
{
    // Performs search only if the keyword wasn't found in the last 5 minutes
    if (!foundKeywordsList.Contains(kw) && content.IndexOf(kw) != -1)
    {
        //
        // code for triggering the alarm
        //

        foundKeywordsList.Add(kw);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would probably work better is to create a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` where you add the found key word and the time that it was found. Then create a method that is called via a timer with the body:

```
foundKeywordsDict = foundKeywordsDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))
                    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp = > kvp.Value)
```

What this will do is create a new dictionary from the existing one where all the keywords have been added within the last 5 min.

EDIT:
There are two types of timers in c#, the `System.Timers.Timer` and the `System.Threading.Timer`. The following is using the later. Using the `System.Threading.Timer`, the `Timer` will create a new thread when the timer hits, calling the `TimerCallback` delegate that you pass in the constructor, and restart the timer. The `TimerCallback` only accepts methods with the signature of `void MethodName(object state)` (it can be static).

For your case, you would want your code to look similar to this:

```
public void RemoveOldFoundKeywords(object state)
{
    lock(foundKeywordsDict) //since you are working with threads, you need to lock the resource
        foundKeywordsDict = foundKeywordsDict.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))
                    .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp = > kvp.Value)
}
```

To create the timer, you would want something similar to this:

```
Using System.Threading;
....

int timerInterval = 60*1000 //one minute in milliseconds
TimerCallback timerCB = new TimerCallback(RemoveOldFoundKeywords);

Timer t = new Timer(
    timerCB,         //the TimerCallback delegate
    null,            //any info to pass into the called method
    0,               //amount of time to wait before starting the timer after creation
    timerInterval);  //Interval between calls in milliseconds
```

Additional information on the `System.Threading.Timer` class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), info for the `System.Timers.Timer` class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and info for the `lock` keyword can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: Could you please provide me an example on how to implement such timer?

Comment: Thank you! Btw, I attempted to debug the RemoveOldFoundKeywords, in a very concise and clear way, but turns out it only works ocasionally (apparently, only when debbuging). Do you see any reason for that strange behavior?

Comment: It should work consistently. The timer will hit every minute while the  method will only remove entries that are more then 5 minutes old. Do you get an exception when the method is called? Or is just nothing happening?

Comment: I think the problem was that I had `.Where(kvp => kvp.Value <= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))` instead of `.Where(kvp => kvp.Value > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5))`. Try switching that and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to periodically clear the foundKeywordsList, you could try this:

```
// Invoke the background monitor
int _5mins = 5 * 60 * 1000;
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PeriodicallyClearList(foundKeywordsList, _5mins));

// Method to clear the list
void PeriodicallyClearList(List<string> toClear, int timeoutInMilliseconds)
{
    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeoutInMilliseconds);
        toClear.Clear();
    }
}
```

You would need to add lock blocks when accessing foundKeywordsList to ensure add and clear don't occur concurrently.

Comment: Actually I don't want to clear the entire list, just remove the first element.